# How can I identify a user who clicked a Facebook Like button on my Blogger blog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the like button on my blog and i need to get, through the api, who clicked it. I want to know the user id or something that can get me to that.

I am developing an application for my thesis that does data excavation on social networks and visualizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, getting this information will require an install. Since you mentioned you're using Blogger, that pretty much leaves you with JavaScript.

The best thing to do is ensure they've installed *before* they've hit the "Like" button, as that will be easier to deal with. Installing looks like this (using some jQuery too, for brevity):

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status 
    });

    $('#button').click(function(evt)
    {
       FB.login(function(response)
       {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                // yay! logged in!
            }
       }); 
    });
```

Now that you have an install, all you need to do is hook in to the "Like" event.

```js
FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(url)
{
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
   {
       if (response.status === 'connected')
       {
           var userId =  response.authResponse.userID;

           // you now have the userId and the URL of the object they liked.
       }
    }
});
```

Once you have a user ID and URL, you can fire off an AJAX request somewhere so you can keep track of who liked what.

More documentation:

- [JS FB SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
- [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)
- [`FB.getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)
- [`FB.Event.subscribe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)